# alternative to detach jQuery

Tags: jquery

Basically I'm looking for a light weight filtering system that will display selected elements and hide those not selected, however some classes may have two selectors in example:

```
<li class="one"> </li>
<li class="one two"> </li>
<li class="three"> </li>
```

So basically if I selected show one and two it would hide three, however if I selected show only two it would show only two, initially I had thought detach may work but it seems a rather long winded way, I'm hoping there is a short cut.

Comment: What's wrong with using `hide()` and `show()`?

Comment: I hadn't thought of it, show(), hide() and not(), would work?  My main thinking is the length of the list, it could work, I think I was trying to make a simple answer more complex than it really needed to be.